# open several csv and put them in a data frame

Tags: r, csv

I have several csv files in one folder. Each file represents the data of one participant. I am trying to create a function to open all the files and put them in one data frame.  For the first file, the function should read the header, but not for the others.  I have tried this:

```
files<-list.files(path="D:/r")
for(i in 1:length(files)){
if(i==1){
    matriz<-read.csv(files [i], header=TRUE)
}else{
    tmp<-read.csv(files[i],header=FALSE)
    matriz<-rbind(matrix,tmp)
}
}
```

However, it doesn´t work... Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: And by "doesn't work" you mean what exactly?

Comment: I obtain the following error: Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Comment: Then that's likely because you typed `matrix` rather than `matriz` in your `rbind`.

Comment: that is true, but it still doesn´t work... now I obtain the following error: Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'...

Comment: Well, i don't know exactly what code you're running anymore. But that error likely means you are using the name of a function where R expected an atomic-valued variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your column names when `i==1` and assign them to `tmp` so you can `rbind()`.

```
setwd("") # your path here
files <- list.files()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  if (i==1) {
    matriz <- read.csv(files[i], header=TRUE)
    cname <- names(matriz)       # get column names when reading in header
  } else {
    tmp <- read.csv(files[i], header=FALSE)
    names(tmp) <- cname          # assign column names so you can bind
    matriz <- rbind(matriz,tmp)  # change error in matrix/z
  }
}
```

Comment: Eric, thanks a lot. That code works, but it gives the name of the columns for each participant and I don't want that. What I want is to merge the data frames of the last 19 participants into the data frame of the first participant. So, the instruction should read the names of the columns only for the first participant.

Comment: I don't follow, @unomas83. The code only gets headers and defines `cname` when `i==1`. In subsequent runs, `tmp` comes in without headers and `R` assigns new variable names. You want to `rbind()` `tmp` to `matriz`, so we run `names(tmp)` to make sure `tmp` has the same column names. I think it should do exactly what you want. You might consider sharing some screenshots of what is not working.

Comment: thanks again, Eric. As you can see in the following output, it gives me the name of the columns for each participant ![Valid XHTML](http://subefotos.com/ver/?2cffd4fbec7aa0d1c05068ff3848a808o.jpg).

Comment: do your other files have headers? i was assuming not since you specified `headers=FALSE`. if the other files have headers, change the code in `else` to `headers=TRUE`. the `names(tmp) <- cname` code will rename them to match the headers in `i==1` if they are different.

Comment: Eric, thanks a lot. It works now! Yes, all the files had headers as they are data for each participant automatically generated by a software. Now I will try to understand what the function is actually doing, but it works perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and fast way to read multiple data frames and bind them into a single data frame using `fread`

```
# Load library
  library(data.table)

# Get a List of all files named with a key word, say all `.csv` files
  filenames <- list.files("C:/your/folder", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

 # Load and bind all data sets
   data <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I had not defined the matrix which I was binding to.

eg: 
    df <- data.frame(variable=character(), x=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## before running the if .

```
for(i in 1:3000){

filename<- paste(c("Aone.txt.", i), collapse = "")
x <- read.table(filename, header=TRUE, sep=" ", row.names = NULL)
df<- rbind(df,x)    
print(i)
print(nrow(df))
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. Please don't post a comment as an answer because of your low reputation.